# Condition to become a space $T_1$

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is $T_1$ if the diagonal in the product topology $X$ * $X$ is the intersection of family of open sets.

Comment: In order to show the spce $T_1$ i think to start with two distinct points. Probably have to start with (x,y) not in diagonal. Then what happens? puzzeled

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be two points in $X$. Then $(x,y)$ is not in the diagonal $\triangle$. By assumption there is an open set $U\supset\triangle$ such that $(x,y)\notin U$. Now look at the subspace $X\times\{y\}$ of $X\times X$ which is homeomorphic to $X$ via the projection $(z,y)\mapsto z$. Then the projection of $U\cap X\times \{y\}$ is an open set containing $y$ but not $x$.

Comment: Not getting.Please expalain

Comment: I've written more now.